# Sitecore PowerShell script to convert Sitecore Date field data to other format

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am having Sitecore's Date field data coming as `20230804T000000Z`, I also have time coming as `11 am`. The Date is coming from Sitecore date field, and time from Single-Line Text field as below.

[image]

I need to combine these two and get the date and time as this format `2023-08-04T03:02:36+00:00`
I got the date and time in my PowerShell using

```
$field_date_range_start_date = $item.Fields["Event Start Date"]
$field_date_range_start_time =$item.Fields["Event Start Time"]
```

have tried using

1. `split()` but out don't help out it says this is not supported
2. something like

   ```
   $year = $dateString.Substring(0, 4)
   $month = $dateString.Substring(4, 2)
   $day = $dateString.Substring(6, 2)
   ```

and concat these to get `yyyy-MM-dd` format but didn't work out it says Substring() is not supported

3. `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` also didn't help work out it says this is not supported
4. `[DateTime]::ParseExact( $field_date_range_start_date, "yyyy-MM-dd", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)`
   gives error in  ParseExact

Is there anyway that I can achieve converting `20230804T000000Z` to `yyyy-MM-dd` and combining with `11 am`($field_date_range_start_time) and finally get my date variable to have format used in this sample `2023-08-04T03:02:36+00:00`, using Sitecore PowerShell Script as I am exporting some of my data

Thanks

Comment: You could have used date time field instead and then that would have returned the data in ISO format as you intend...

Answer (score 2):

```
function Convert-DateFormat {
    param(
        [string]$inputDateString
    )
    $inputDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($inputDateString, "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ", $null)
    $outputDateString = $inputDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")
    return $outputDateString
}
```

You can use this method to convert your date to the new format.
You need to use also Sitecore powershell extension to update the fields

```
$item = Get-Item .
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$currentDateFieldName=$item.Fields["YourDateFieldName"].Value;
$item.Fields["YourDateFieldName"].Value =Convert-DateFormat($currentDateFieldName");
$item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date format using Powershell using this way.

```
$homedate = Get-Item "/sitecore/content/Home/Sample"

$date2 = $homedate.Fields["date"].Value

$dateTime = ([sitecore.dateutil]::IsoDateToDateTime($homedate["date"]))

Write-Host $dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

It will give you the output like below.

[image]

And using the `[string]::Concat($string1, $string2)` you can combine them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following helper to format date in powershell.

```
$date = $item.Fields["Date"].Value
$isoDate =  [Sitecore.DateUtil]::IsoDateToDateTime($date)
Write-Host ($isoDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

This would return in the format as below.

[image]

Though I would recommend you to change the field type from date to datetime instead.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.DateField] $dateField = $item.Fields["Event Start Date"]
$dateString = $dateField.DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$timeString = $item["Event Start Time"]
$yourString = [string]::Format("{0}T{1}",$dateString, $timeString)
```

The format in the `$yourString` variable can be changed as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below script

```
$field_date_range_start_date = $item.Fields["Event Start Date"]
$field_date_range_start_time =$item.Fields["Event Start Time"]
# Parse date and time
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($field_date_range_start_date.Value, "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ", $null)
$time = Get-Date -Date $field_date_range_start_time.Value -Format "HH:mm"
# Combine date and time
$combinedDateTime = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + $time + "+00:00"
# Output the combined date and time
Write-Output $combinedDateTime
```

This will return like below

[image]

Hope this helps!